# How to declare a class as DataContract that is in Business Layer in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on asmx web service to WCF conversion.

I have a class called `Customer` and `Customers` (Array of Customers) in my BLL (Business Layer)

Since the `classes are already defined in Business Layer` .

How to declare them as `Data Contract` in Service Layer with out redefining them ?

Since, it has already reference to Business layer. Please suggest

Where do we need to **place** Data Contracts usually? In Interface or Separate classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One amoung the best approach would be to placing all serializable types (`Data Contracts` or `Service Contracts`) in a single project (like Infrastructure Library) and then refer same in required project.

Comment: A nice and clean idea. Thanks